# Separate data frames for each dictionary keys() dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was able to create separated DF for each key of the dict. However, wondering a way more dinamically, is possible: 
My code that is working.

```
    dataDct.keys()
    dict_keys(['PETR4_Dai', 'PETR4_H1_', 'PETR4_M15', 'PETR4_M5_', 
               'PETR4_Mon','PETR4_Wee'])

     try:
    # Petr4
     dfp5 = dataDct['PETR4_M5_'].drop(['<TICKVOL>','<SPREAD>'],axis=1)
     dfp15 = dataDct['PETR4_M15'].drop(['<TICKVOL>','<SPREAD>'],axis=1)
     dfph1 = dataDct['PETR4_H1_'].drop(['<TICKVOL>','<SPREAD>'],axis=1)
     dfpd = dataDct['PETR4_Dai'].drop(['<TICKVOL>','<SPREAD>'],axis=1)
     dfpw = dataDct['PETR4_Wee'].drop(['<TICKVOL>','<SPREAD>'],axis=1)
     dfpm = dataDct['PETR4_Mon'].drop(['<TICKVOL>','<SPREAD>'],axis=1)
     except:
         pass
```

Thereby, I have tried to get it more dinamicaly:

```
      #name of the DF:
      lables = list(dataDct.keys())

      df = []
      for i in dataDct.keys():
           df.append(dataDct[i].drop(['<TICKVOL>','<SPREAD>'],axis=1))

      listup = pd.DataFrame()
      for label,value in zip(lables,df):
             listup[label] = [(value)]

      or 
      listup = pd.DataFrame()
      for label,value in zip(lables,df):
             listup[label] = [pd.DataFrame.from_dict(value)]
```

All cases did not work and I also tried with list and dictionaries. no success.I could not get it separated as well.

Wondering how to create DF for each key of the dict..using the key as name of the DF; 
Any help would be appreaciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do what you want is to create a new dictionary whose keys are the same as the keys in your preexisting dictionary, and whose values are DataFrames. In this sense you can dynamically create DataFrames (values) with names (keys), and call on them at will. (You could even assign a `.name` to the DataFrames that match the key name as well.)

```
import pandas as pd

new_dict = {}
for key in dataDct.keys():
    new_dict[key] = pd.DataFrame()
    new_dict[key].name = key
```

Comment: Thanks for you response! .. Not sure if I got correctly, because,I´m trying to link both DF, but, the new_dict creates a list of empty DF.  Also, I tried to associate values doing another for loop with : 
        total = {}
        for i, ii in zip(new_dict, dataDct.values()):
               total[i] = (ii)
It backs to the start.. a dict like initial one.  .. Trying to convert to DF (Series) .. it generates messy DF,s
        total = pd.DataFrame()
for i, ii in zip(new_dict, dataDct.values()):
    total[i] = [(ii)]